# Torque for chloropleth and bubble maps?

Tags: torque

Torque looks like a brilliant tool. However, can I use the same tool for chloropleth maps for visualizing monthly/annual changes of GDP, health expenditure, population growth etc. over the past 10 years? Will it work with bubble charts (changing the size of bubbles rather than just mapping singular events?).